# Why is 'existing_client()' function returning the info 5 times rather than just once?

Tags: python

Every time I call the function it returns the info 5 times when I only want the line one time.

[image]

```
def existing_client():
    client_number = input("What is the existing customers number? (type like this 123-456-7890) ")
    with open("clients.txt", 'r') as openfile:
        for line in openfile:
            for part in line.split():
                if line.startswith(client_number):
                    print(line)
```

Comment: What do you think `for part in line.split():` does?

Comment: @BillLynch it returns the values stored in a line doesn't it?

Comment: I solved this now, @BillLynch thank you for the hint. I just started learning python this last week so I'm kinda just fooling around with things learning as I go. Thank you! :)